# How can I access context from a <script setup> tag in vue3?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-script-setup

Previously I used the standard **< script >** tag with the setup function within it:

```js
    <script>
    import { ref } from 'vue'
    import useLogin from '../composables/useLogin'

    const email = ref('')
    const password = ref('')

    export default {
    setup(props, context){
        const {error, login} = useLogin()

        const handleLoginSubmit = async () => {
            await login(email.value, password.value)
            if(!error.value){
                context.emit('login')
            }
            router.push({name: 'home'})
        }
        return { email, password, handleLoginSubmit }
    
        }
    
    }
    </script>
```

Now I tried to switch to the **< script setup >** tag, but I don't know how to access the **context** attribute here.

```js
    <script setup>
    import { ref } from 'vue'
    import useLogin from '../composables/useLogin'
    import router from '../router'
    
    const email = ref('')
    const password = ref('')
    
    const {error, login} = useLogin()
    
    const handleLoginSubmit = async () => {
        await login(email.value, password.value)
        if(!error.value){
            context.emit('login')
        }
        router.push({name: 'home'})
    }
    </script>
```

I get the following error due to the missing definition of the context.

```js
    Uncaught ReferenceError: context is not defined
```

I tried to import context from vue in different ways, but nothing seems to be the correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Context` is not available in `<script setup`> if you want to use emits and props, there are some helpers(macros) exposed to you.

In your case you are trying to use `emit`, so in script setup it is going to be something like:

```js
<script setup>
const emit = defineEmits(['event1','event2']);
...
emit('event1','some-value');
</script>
```

So, in your example, that would be:

```js
const emit = defineEmits(['login']);
const handleLoginSubmit = async () => {
        await login(email.value, password.value)
        if(!error.value){
            emit('login')
        }
        router.push({name: 'home'})
    }
```

For props, you use `defineProps`. See [this](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#defineprops-defineemits) for more info